# Setting up a matlab global optimization with compute cluster

Tags: matlab

I have matlab running on a windows machine, on another (Ubuntu) machine a I have perl program that launches simulations on a cluster and then collects the results.

There are 8 parameters that are varied and fed into the simulator, the values of which are discrete and finite, but there are well over several million possible configurations, the output is a singular value (searching for a global mimimum). Each simulation takes about 8 minutes and I can run ~800 simulations at a time on the cluster.

I was hoping to use matlab to perform some sort of global optimization/intelligent search/perhaps genetic algorithm, but am at a loss as to how to approach this? I basically need to get matlab to give me 800 configurations it wants run, send that over ssh, have matlab wait for the results, feed the results back into matlab, and then get the next set of 800 configurations in a loop. I don't yet know for sure if the output of the simulator will follow a pattern with respect to the inputs (but pretty sure they will), but either way, I also would need a way to determine when to stop simulating, but am happy just to get the the first bit up and running for now.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!!

Essentially, the setup:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Don't pick the configurations yourself. Let whatever solving/minimization technique that you're using vary the parameter values for you. That's what they're designed to do. You'll probably have to run it on the cluster too as it'll be tightly coupled to results of each simulation. What solving/minimization technique you use will be dependent on the problem you're solving so I can't suggest anything. You can take advantage of the cluster by subdividing the space of parameter values among the 800 (or however many) simultaneous searches you perform. Each search will return a minimum or fail to find one (some parameter combination might not converge or may have numerical issues, etc.). The global minimum can then be obtain my taking the minimum of all of the successful searches. You'll need to be careful that you include all of the parameter space when you divide it up (you might want to overlap the regions a bit). Also your search will need be careful to not get caught in local minima of course and find the true minimum of each region - this should guide what technique you choose.